# How to generate HMAC

Tags: node.js, go, cryptography, hmac

I need to create an Hmac in Go. I have created an Hmac in nodejs, need to generate the same Hamc in Go. Tried following code but getting exactly different output. I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
This is what I tried

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func ComputeHmac256(message string, secret string) string {
    key := []byte(secret)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    h.Write([]byte(message))
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ComputeHmac256("sms1", "b5fb5b3a65b8429693c3a029308e2e46"))
}
Output: JVN7kUPFL0aQ09lIH4YOsFJA3A2faqTuu6zIaYo61VI=
```

**Need go equivalent of following nodejs code**

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    text = 'sms1',
    key = 'b5fb5b3a65b8429693c3a029308e2e46'
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key)
hash.update(text)
var value = hash.digest('hex')
// Output 
25537b9143c52f4690d3d9481f860eb05240dc0d9f6aa4eebbacc8698a3ad552
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the same encoding in your Go program as you do in your Node.js program ([hex](http://godoc.org/encoding/hex)):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func ComputeHmac256(message string, secret string) string {
    key := []byte(secret)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    h.Write([]byte(message))
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ComputeHmac256("sms1", "b5fb5b3a65b8429693c3a029308e2e46"))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-1yePFeipT

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim. Your answer really helped me.

Comment: If I want to write more data in hmac, Can I use h.Write() multiple times? or do I need to reset it before I write next value?

Comment: @Tim, Oh my bro, you saved me!!! I didn't figure out how to use `hmac.Write()` and `hmac.sum()`.  so I put the message into `sum()` and the result drove me crazy. Anyway, thanks a lot.